# No protocol handler was valid for the URL for unix sockets

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to use a unix socket with apache 2.4.10 and I keep getting the error `No protocol handler was valid for the URL /foo.`

I have `mod_proxy_uwscgi` installed and enabled.

My Virtual Host looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin me@example.com
    ServerName foo.example.com

    <Location />
            ProxyPass unix:/path/to/socket.sock|uwscgi://
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Output of `apachectl -M`

```
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 php5_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared)
 proxy_ajp_module (shared)
 proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
 proxy_uwsgi_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 socache_shmcb_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
```

I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Can you post the output of `apachectl -M`?

Comment: @mzhaase added to question

Comment: Is that `|` in your config actually in the real apache conf? If so, that may be your issue - I am not sure pipe syntax is supported in the context you are trying to use it

Comment: @iwaseatenbyagrue yes it is. Without it this fails a config test unless I change the address to `unix:///path/to/socket.sock`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo. It is not uwscgi, it is uwsgi.

From the [UWSGI docs](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Apache.html):

> Starting from Apache 2.4.9, support for Unix sockets has been added. The syntax is pretty simple:
>
> `ProxyPass / unix:/var/lib/uwsgi/app1.sock|uwsgi://uwsgi-uds-app1/`
>
> `ProxyPass / unix:/var/lib/uwsgi/app2.sock|uwsgi://uwsgi-uds-app2/`

Comment: Thanks, now I'm getting a error from UWSGI saying `DNS lookup failure for: uwsgi-uds-assets-api`

Comment: @Arcath Is your Apache up to date?

Comment: As upto date as it can be on debian jessie. Thinking I need to enable the sid repos for it

Comment: @Arcath Do you have a trailing slash after the uri? `uwsgi://uwsgi-uds-assets-api/` <- there needs to be a slash.

Comment: yeah I have the trailing slash

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to have the following line in place of what you currently have: `ProxyPass uwscgi://path/to/socket.sock`

All else aside, the unix/uwscgi paths are provided as URIs, which should be of the form PROTOCOL://PATH. 
If PATH is a canonical path, you would have, e.g. unix:///dev/null.